# Unable to read input from a form in php

Tags: php, wampserver

I'm unable to read input data from a form in php running on wamp server.
Following is the code:

```
    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $doctype = $docnbr = $entrydt = $incserno = $incsernodt = $recdfr = $sub = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $doctype = test_input($_POST["doctype"]);   
    $docnbr = test_input($_POST["docnbr"]);
    $entrydt = test_input($_POST["entrydt"]);
    $incserno = test_input($_POST["incserno"]);
    $incsernodt = test_input($_POST["incsernodt"]);
    $recdfr = test_input($_POST["recdfr"]);
    $sub = test_input($_POST["sub"]);
    }

   function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
   }
   ?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; margin-top:10px">
    <div class="form-group row" style="width:75%">
    <label for="documenttype" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Type of Document</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
    <select class="form-control" id="documenttype" name="doctype">
    <option selected="selected">Select</option>
    <option>File</option>
    <option>Letter</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row" style="width:75%">
    <label for="documentnumber" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Document Number</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="docnumber" name="docnbr" placeholder="<?php echo $max_docno; ?>" readonly>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row" style="width:75%">
    <label for="documententrydate" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Entry Date</label> 
    <div class="col-xs-10">   
    <input class="form-control" type='date' id="entrydate" name="entrydt" />
    </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row" style="width:75%">
    <label for="incomingserno" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Incoming Serial Number</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="incomingserno" name="incserno">
    </div>
    <label for="indated" class="col-xs-1 col-form-label">Dated</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
    <input class="form-control" type="date" id="incomingsernodt" name="incsernodt">
    </div>
    </div>

   <div class="form-group row" style="width:75%">
   <label for="recdfrom" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Received From</label>
   <div class="col-xs-10">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" id="recdfrom" name="recdfr">
   </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group row" style="width:75%">
   <label for="subject" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Subject</label>
   <div class="col-xs-10">
   <textarea class="form-control" id="subject" name="sub"></textarea>
   </div>
   </div>

   <center>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
   <input type="reset" value="Reset">
   </center>
   </form>
```

changed `<form menthod="post"` to `<form method="post"`

Nothing is being captured in the variables:
`$doctype`, `$docnbr`, `$entrydt`, $incserno`,`$incsernodt`,`$recdfr`,`$sub`.
I have also tried using`isset()` function to capture the state of submit button instead of checking for the request method but to no avail, I'm not able to capture the form data from the php form on wamp server.

Comment: Its method not menthod dear

Comment: Typo error : `<form menthod="post"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tou must change from `menthod to method` 
and also prit your variable to see it.

```
<?php
        // define variables and set to empty values
        $doctype = $docnbr = $entrydt = $incserno = $incsernodt = $recdfr = $sub = "";

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $doctype = test_input($_POST["doctype"]);   
        $docnbr = test_input($_POST["docnbr"]);
        $entrydt = test_input($_POST["entrydt"]);
        $incserno = test_input($_POST["incserno"]);
        $incsernodt = test_input($_POST["incsernodt"]);
        $recdfr = test_input($_POST["recdfr"]);
        $sub = test_input($_POST["sub"]);
        echo " $doctype $docnbr $entrydt $incserno $incsernodt $recdfr $sub";

        }

       function test_input($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
       }
       ?>

        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; margin-top:10px">
        <div class="form-group row" style="width:75%">
        <label for="documenttype" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Type of Document</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="documenttype" name="doctype">
        <option selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option>File</option>
        <option>Letter</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row" style="width:75%">
        <label for="documentnumber" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Document Number</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="docnumber" name="docnbr" placeholder="<?php echo $max_docno; ?>" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row" style="width:75%">
        <label for="documententrydate" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Entry Date</label> 
        <div class="col-xs-10">   
        <input class="form-control" type='date' id="entrydate" name="entrydt" />
        </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row" style="width:75%">
        <label for="incomingserno" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Incoming Serial Number</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="incomingserno" name="incserno">
        </div>
        <label for="indated" class="col-xs-1 col-form-label">Dated</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
        <input class="form-control" type="date" id="incomingsernodt" name="incsernodt">
        </div>
        </div>

       <div class="form-group row" style="width:75%">
       <label for="recdfrom" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Received From</label>
       <div class="col-xs-10">
       <input class="form-control" type="text" id="recdfrom" name="recdfr">
       </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group row" style="width:75%">
       <label for="subject" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Subject</label>
       <div class="col-xs-10">
       <textarea class="form-control" id="subject" name="sub"></textarea>
       </div>
       </div>

       <center>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
       <input type="reset" value="Reset">
       </center>
       </form>
```